# RailsApp help Rspec Tutorial undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Hi I am working on Daniel Kehoe's [Rspec Tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/rspec.html).  Everything went fine until I created the file spec/features/visitor/home_page_spec.rb .  When I put the following test code in it

```
# Feature: Home Page
#   As a visitor
#   I want to visit a home page
#   So I can learn more about the website
feature 'Home Page' do

  # Scenario: Visit the Home Page
  #   Given I am a visitor
  #   When I visit the home page
  #   Then I should see "Welcome"
  scenario 'Visit the Home Page' do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_content 'Welcome'
  end

end
```

and run  rspec spec/features/visitor/home_page_spec.rb from the terminal, I got the error below.    I get that the method was not defined but Daniel's tutorial just tells you to put the code in the folder above.  Guess I am missing something.  Thank you

```
rails-bootstrap/spec/features/visitor/home_page_spec.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': 
undefined method `feature' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: add `require 'spec_helper'`

Answer (score 2):

What's in your *.rspec* file in the project directory? You should have:

```
--color
--format documentation
--require spec_helper
--require rails_helper
```

If the  *.rspec* file is set up properly, you will not need additional `require` statements in your spec files.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I get **rake test** to run is to add the below require to **test/integration/home_page_test.rb**

```
require 'minitest/rails/capybara'
```

This line is already in **test/test_helper.rb** so I'm not sure why it isn't picking it up. I also tried adding the **.rspec** file with the options suggested by Daniel. If nothing else works, try that.